# refresh the selected option in the appended row

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know how to give the proper title for this problem, so sorry if this is confusing you all.

First, I have a function to append one row inside a table. Each row will have a dropdown ( select tag) with some option that I retrieve from database. To generate the dropdown, I have a get() function that when the page loaded, I get the output of a php file to show the dropdown with data inside it from my database. i put it inside `<div align=center class='finish'></div>`. From the default condition, there are already 3 rows with the same format, so I need to start the get() from the beginning. But the problem is that I want to set the dropdown inside the new appended row without refreshing the other existing dropdown. the logic is, when I already choose some option from existing dropdown, an then I want to add new row, I don't want to refreshed the dropdown that already selected.

get() for dropdown function:

```
$.get("getfinishlist.php", function(item) {
  $('.finish').html(item);
});
```

addrow table function for append row:

```
function addrow_table() { //#p_rows is the tbody of the table
  $('#p_rows').append("<tr><td><div align=center><input type='text' size='5' class='section' name='section[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>"
  +"<td><div class='desc' style='font-size:11px;'></div></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center class='finish'></div><input type='hidden' class='hfinish'></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='5' name='hrd[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='9' name='length[]' class='length' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='4' class='pc' name='pc[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center class='kg'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hkg' name='kg[]'></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center class='price'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hprice' name='price[]'></td>"
  +"<td><div align=center class='amount'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hamount' name='amount[]'></td>"
  +"<td><input type='hidden' style='font-size:11px'>"
  +"<div align='center'>"
  +"<a href='#' id='delrow' style='text-decoration:none;'>"
  +"<div style='border:1px solid #a1a1a1;"
  +"background:#dddddd;"
  +"width:30px;"
  +"border-radius:5px;'>"
  +"X"
  +"</div></a></div></td>"
  +"</tr>");

  $.get("getfinishlist.php", function(item) { //I know this is wrong because every time I start the function, every dropdown refreshed
    $('.finish').html(item);
  });

  return false;
}

$('#addrow').click(function() { //#addrow is a div
  addrow_table();
});
```

the php file to retrieve the dropdown:

```
<?php
  include "config/koneksi.php";
  echo "<select name='finish[]' class='sfinish'>";
  $finish = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM harga");
  while($readf = mysql_fetch_array($finish)){
    echo "<option value='".$readf['finishing']."'>".$readf['finishing']."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
?>
```

I appreciate every answer that everyone give to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to set the result of the ajax request to the newly added row, in that case

```
function addrow_table() { //#p_rows is the tbody of the table
    //store the added row reference in a variable - use appendTo() to return the newly added element reference
    var $row = $("<tr><td><div align=center><input type='text' size='5' class='section' name='section[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>" + "<td><div class='desc' style='font-size:11px;'></div></td>" + "<td><div align=center class='finish'></div><input type='hidden' class='hfinish'></td>" + "<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='5' name='hrd[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>" + "<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='9' name='length[]' class='length' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>" + "<td><div align=center><input type='text' size='4' class='pc' name='pc[]' style='font-size:11px'></div></td>" + "<td><div align=center class='kg'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hkg' name='kg[]'></td>" + "<td><div align=center class='price'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hprice' name='price[]'></td>" + "<td><div align=center class='amount'>0</div><input type='hidden' class='hamount' name='amount[]'></td>" + "<td><input type='hidden' style='font-size:11px'>" + "<div align='center'>" + "<a href='#' id='delrow' style='text-decoration:none;'>" + "<div style='border:1px solid #a1a1a1;" + "background:#dddddd;" + "width:30px;" + "border-radius:5px;'>" + "X" + "</div></a></div></td>" + "</tr>").appendTo('#p_rows');

    $.get("getfinishlist.php", function (item) {
        //find the finish element in the newly added row
        $row.find('.finish').html(item);
    });

    return false;
}

$('#addrow').click(function () { //#addrow is a div
    addrow_table();
});
```

Comment: Ok I will try the code. I will give you feedback soon. thank you.